# How to disable switchable graphics

Tags: drivers, graphics, amd-graphics

I have switchable graphic (Intel + AMD), the problem is AMD isn't providing appropriate drivers for latest versions of linux distros.

As the correct drivers are not available, AMD graphic card is used all the time (while it should be used only while performing high graphic requirement tasks, atleast that's how its done in Windows).

This drains the battery of my laptop a lot faster which is creating problems for me. I have checked that there are no unnecessary processes running.

So I wanted to know if there is a way to only use the Intel graphic card and totally disabling the AMD card?